# Which jars to import from apache POI library for reading and writing only .xls and xlsx (MS Excel files)?

Tags: android, apache, xlsx

I had downloaded poi-bin-3.10-FINAL-20140208.zip from apache website. It containes 13 jars (total 12 MB size). If I put all the jars in my android projects libs folder then while compiling it says "**Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 2**" I think It happens due to to much of methods in the project then the maximum allowed.
so The question is exactly which of the jars should I have to import to my project so I don't get the dalvik conversion error and also **No Class Found Error**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the below given jar files to export `xlsx` files.

```
poi-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
```

Please note, you have to use `SXSSF (Streaming Usermodel API)` to resolve Java heap space issues.

Comment: I get NOCLASSdefFound Error for SXSSFWorkbook although I had imported those jars as you mentioned

Comment: `poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar` contains `SXSSFWorkbook`.